# En español, ¿hay más en palabras de género femenino o masculino?

Tags: género, sustantivos

Me interesa saber si en español hay más sustantivos femeninos o masculinos. ¿Hay información al respecto?

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish Language, te sugiero que te pases por [ask]. Podrias ser un poco mas especifico para saber que es lo que buscas?

Comment: Supongo que lo que busques es saber son las estadisticas acerca de cuantas palbaras pertenecen a un genero u otro en el idioma espanol.

Comment: Without doing much research, I guess the answer could be something like "it depends". To start with, what is the scope (which variation of Spanish)? And then we could take any of the many offical resources, such as the DRAE, _diccionario de americanismos_, etc. but, which version of them? Then, I don't think they have statistics per version about stuff like number of male/female words, and then it would change with a new version. In case that you find any kind of statistics about it it could change really quickly. This is an interesting question, but you might need to "scope" it.

Comment: ¿hay más en palabras de género femenino o masculino? La respuesta corta. **Hay más palabras de género masculino**. @CarlosAlejo y jlliagre lo han demostrado ampliamente usando fuentes de información diferentes. Gran esfuerzo de ambos para una pregunta que estuvo a un voto de ser cerrada ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Aquí son cifras calculadas a partir de una lista de 107638 palabras (MM.nom.txt) disponible en [Freeling](http://devel.cpl.upc.edu/freeling):

- Masc.: 53724 : 49,91 %
- Fem.: 49700 : 46,17 %
- Ambos gén.: 4214 : 3,91 %

La tercera letra del código final indica el género de la palabra :

> ...
>   cifra cifra NC**F**S000
>   ...
>   número número NC**M**S000

Más detalles aqui:

```
código    #     %
  CN    121  0,11 ambos géneros no número
  CP   2089  1,94 ambos géneros plural
  CS   2004  1,86 ambos géneros singular
  FN    932  0,87 femenino no número
  FP  24407 22,68 femenino plural
  FS  24361 22,63 femenino singular
  MN    883  0,82 masculino no número 
  MP  26686 24,79 masculino plural
  MS  26155 24,30 masculino singular
```

Si solo tomamos in cuenta las palabras con un género claro y al singular, la proporción es 48,22 femeninos frente a 51,77 masculinos.

Puesto que el sitio [Freeling](http://devel.cpl.upc.edu/freeling/browser/trunk/data) tiene diccionarios de otros idiomas, especialmente del grupo iberorromance pero también francés e italiano, su análisis produce estas proporciones (masculino/femenino):

```
0,92 portugués
0,97 gallego
1,06 catalán
1,08 español
1,19 francés
1,39 asturiano
1,43 italiano
```

No se puede concluir nada excepcional de estas cifras, sino que la proporción es bastante equilibrada con estas lenguas romances, especialmente cuando la comparamos con el galés (3,32) y el noruego (2,72).

Lo que falta a todas estas estadísticas es una ponderación con la frecuencia de uso de la palabras.

Comment: Interesante fichero, aunque veo que incluye palabras técnicas que no aparecen ni en el DLE ni en el de americanismos (lo que no invalida la respuesta, por supuesto). Eso sí, ¿es posible que en el conteo hayas incluido las variantes en plural? Veo que la cuarta letra del código puede ser S o P según la palabra sea singular o plural. Tal vez deberías restringir la búsqueda solamente a las versiones en singular.

Comment: [Enlace directo a la descarga](http://devel.cpl.upc.edu/freeling/browser/trunk/data/es/dictionary/entries/MM.nom) del fichero mencionado.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo omitir o incluir los plurales no cambia mucho las estadísticas, puesto que no son muchas las palabras solo al singular. También hay algunas palabras solo al plural. Respuesta modificada con más detalles.

Comment: MS/FS da una relación de 1.07. Interesante esfuerzo pero un resultado muy diferente al obtenido por @CarlosAlejo que encontró una relación de 1.35. Estadísticamente sigue la incertidumbre. ;-)

Comment: Es interesante que el asturiano tenga una cifra muy diferente del castellano.  No me sorprende que el gallego y portugués tenga una cifra más femenina (porque el sufijo común de -aje en castellano o -ax(e) en asturiano es masculino, pero el equivalente -agem/-agen en portugués/gallego es femenino).  Tengo una copia digital del *Diccionariu de la llingua asturiana* en mi ordenador y podría hacer un cálculo parecido cuando tenga un rato libre, a ver si coincide con los datos allí.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Me parece un intertesante ejercicio para probar algunas herramientas de BigData que me han tenido entretenido ultimamente, en particular **DataProc** y **DataFlow** de Google. Seria apropiado intentar ponderar la proporcion de uso de las palabras en castellano usando el [corpus][http://googlebooks.byu.edu/x.asp] disponible atraves de google books? (para el castellano son 45 mil millones de palabras publicadas entre 1560 y 2010) . Deberia acotar el corpus a fechas mas reciententes? tal vez soloo entre 1900 y 2010)

Comment: @hlecuanda Lista con los lemas del diccionario que aparecen en la lista de frecuencias del Corpus de Referencia del Español Actual, ordenados por su frecuencia normalizada: [lemario_frecuencias-20110908.txt](http://dirae.es/static/lemario_frecuencias-20110908.txt).

Comment: Entiendo que por genero y singular si busco por la palabra porro, saldrá como un resultado una vez en vez de dos (porro de puerro y el otro de cigarrillo), son dos nombres masculinos pero sirven como sustantivo para cosas diferentes, así que es posible buscar por definiciones en masculino y/o en femenino?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Tomando en cuenta la frecuencia, llego a una igualdad casi perfecta (1,014) pero también aparece que las palabras más frecuentes no suelen ser utilizadas como sustantivos, por ejemplo: de, la, y, a, los, los, no, lo, o, si… Parece que este enfoque es demasiado simplista para obtener cifras indiscutibles.

Comment: @AlexBcn Una razón mas para tomar en cuenta la frecuencia de las palabras que suma todas sus acepciones.

Answer (score 6):

Por dar unas cifras aproximadas, aprovechando que el [DIRAE](http://dirae.es) busca el término de búsqueda en cualquier parte de la definición de una palabra, se obtienen los siguientes resultados:

- `"m."` arroja [37773 resultados](http://dirae.es/palabras/?q=%22m.%22), de los cuales había que eliminar los 5 primeros, que corresponden con siglas que contienen la M (como "S.M.").
- `"f."` arroja [27891 resultados](http://dirae.es/palabras/?q=%22f.%22), de los cuales hay que quitar 2.

Esta búsqueda tiene en cuenta los sustantivos como "oso" y "osa", que disponen de las dos variantes. "Oso" aparece en los resultados de la primera búsqueda, y "osa" en los de la segunda. También tiene en cuenta palabras que se usan de forma invariante en los dos géneros, como "colmenero", definida como "m. y f. Persona que tiene colmenas o cuida de ellas". Estas palabras estarían contenidas en ambas búsquedas.

Si dividimos, tenemos `37768 / 27889 = 1.3542`

Por tanto, tendríamos una proporción aproximada de **4 palabras masculinas por cada 3 femeninas** (por simplificar mucho la expresión). Nótese que el DIRAE hace uso exclusivamente del diccionario de la RAE. Quedan excluidos, por tanto, todos los términos que aparecen en el diccionario de americanismos de la ASALE. Es de esperar, en todo caso, que la proporción no varíe considerablemente al haberse calculado con una muestra poblacional lo suficientemente amplia.

Comment: Primero se me hizo curioso que la búsqueda retornara sólo 55 mil palabras. Luego es más curioso aún que la otra respuesta esta basada en en el doble de palabras y que la relación entre masculinas y femeninas de esa otra respuesta sea sólo 1.08 mientras que aquí tenemos 1.35. El esfuerzo de ambas respuestas es de admirar, pero estadísticamente los único que demuestran los dos resultados es que hay gran probabilidad de que haya más palabras masculinas que femeninas (lo que _a priori_ era de esperarse), pero las proporciones siguen siendo inciertas.

Comment: @DGaleano la otra respuesta está basada en el doble de palabras porque la lista que usa incluye los plurales.